# Automatically Transcode Video and Upload to Cloud

Tags: video, nas, amazon-s3

I'm looking for a solution to take video files from my HD Camera and automate transcoding to a smaller format and then uploading to the cloud (AWS or otherwise).

The ideal workflow would be, I have a NAS or a folder where I could simply drag the raw files from the camera to. The NAS/computer would see new files there and automatically transcode the video to settings I have already picked and save them to a folder that is sync'd with AWS S3 or some other cloud storage system.

I know that freenas and such will do somehting similar for xbox360 and ps3 transcoding - can I tap into this for my solution?

Comment: We would need to know what NAS you are running to know if it could do any of this, or otherwise if you have a server running on your lan and what OS it has.

Comment: As per @Paul's comment, if we knew what OS you're running we could provide an answer. Linux is amazingly powerful at such things, and knocking up a script to detect new files, transcode and upload isn't hard.

Answer (score 1):

So there is different things to do:

- monitor the content of the folder you're dropping the raw files into
- shrinking the new file and moving the result into the NAS
- sending the NAS file to S3

To monitor the first folder and run the converter, a simple script can do this.
To convert from DV HD to mp4, [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) can do that easily using a single command line.
Sending to the NAS can be done by syncing a folder on your machine and a folder on the NAS. NAS offer different possibilies to do this sync.
Sending from the NAS to Amazon S3 is supported by some NAS (Synology for instance).

In addition:
- it may be possible to sync a PC folder to S3 or Google Cloud directly without the NAS doing it.
- it may be possible to feed ffmpeg directly with the camera output stream (virtual file as input to ffmpeg).

Comment: cyberduck can sync a folder to S3